# Change backend interface language from Joomla

Tags: joomla

Hello I installed the Joomla and the backend console when I login in have the English language.

How can I make the language interface of backend from English to another language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, you can install languages by:

1. Going to **Extensions** >> **Language Manager** >> Install Language**
2. You will then be provided with a list of language to choose from. So select the language of your choice then click **Install**
3. The go back to **Extensions** >> **Language Manager**  and on the left hand side, click **Installed - Administrator**

You can then select the language you installed as your default admin backend language